# How do you concatenate columns from an excel file with the same name on the 0 axis using python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am a beginner in Python. After hours of searching, I can't find the solution to my problem.

I have more than 2500 columns named `Left pedal torque`, `Right pedal torque` and `Delta time` that I would like to combine into only 3 columns. I would like the columns of the same name to be concatenated end to end into one column. Here is a screenshot of an excerpt from the basic Excel file and the resulting file I would like to have in Python.

*Start file :*

[image]

*Desired final file :*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)/[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) :

```
out = (pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
            .set_axis(df.columns.str.split(".", expand=True), axis=1)
            .stack().sort_index(level=[1,0], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
            [["Left pedal torque", "Right pedal torque", "Delta time"]]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    Left pedal torque  Right pedal torque   Delta time
0                   0                   0            0
1          7039698124           271539712  0,021798503
2          6168807507          2788786173  0,003650174
3          5805936337           344928813  0,003649631
4          4717323303           344928813  0,003905165
5          4209303856           396301198  0,003708225
6          3556136131          4256568432  0,003690864
7          2467523098          4329957485  0,003893772
8          2104651928          4843681335  0,003684896
9          7547717571          2568618774  0,003764648
10         6749401093          2862175226  0,003915473
11         6023659229          3229120731   0,00358724
12         5515639782          3596066236   0,00358941
13         4427026749          3742844582  0,003833008
14         3846432924          4036400795  0,003631185
15         3265839338          4476735592  0,003626845
16         2394948721          4843681335  0,003851454
17         1886929393          5284015656  0,003651801
```

If you need to create a new sheet with the resulting dataframe, use this :

```
out = (pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
            .set_axis(df.columns.str.split(".", expand=True), axis=1)
            .stack()[["Left pedal torque", "Right pedal torque", "Delta time"]]
)

with pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", mode="a",
                     engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    start_row = 0
    for _, g in out.groupby(level=1, dropna=False, sort=False):
        g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2", index=False, startrow=start_row)
        start_row += len(g)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I fixed the sheet names and you're welcome ;)